# OpenShift Online: Change gear size of existing scaled application

Tags: openshift

I have a Python 2.7 scaled app that I need to switch from small to medium gears. Is there any way to do that besides completely destroying the application and recreating it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [new features page](https://blog.openshift.com/new-features-for-april-2014/) from openshift, there see:

```
rhc create-app <clone> --from-app <existing> --scaling --gear-size medium
```

you may need to use the parameter --namespace followed by your domain name if you are using more than one domain.

This enables you to clone an existing application into a new application and change scaling behaviour and gear size.

EDIT:
for some reason the command tries to download the snapshot to the client (and not copy it directly from the original app to the new app), with a fairly big application and a gz file of around 450MB, the fetching of the snapshot broke after some time...

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use the rhc snapshot feature to create a backup of your application, then delete that gear, create a new one that is the size you want, and use the rhc snapshot restore to push your code to the new gear.